# How to select random rows in a dataset and modify their values?

Tags: python

I have a dataset of 12000 rows and 3 columns; I want to randomly select 600 rows from this dataset and modify their values ( the values of a specific column).  Is there any method in python that can do this?

Comment: try `df.sample(600)`

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

def random_select():
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') # read the dataset
    df = df.sample(n=600) # randomly select 600 rows
    df['column'] = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=len(df)) # modify the values of a specific column
    df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False) # save the modified dataset
    return df # return the modified dataset
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    random_select()
```

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by this line of code                                                  if __name__ == '__main__':
    random_select()

Comment: @SoumiaBibi You should read this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: But, sir, the output of your method is a dataset with only 600 rows. I want the dataset to be 12000 rows, including the 600 modified rows (600 rows modified + 600 non-modified)

Answer (score 0):

By the help of this :

```
df.sample(n=600)
# and then you can call the colum you want by using 
pandas.loc function and edit according to your wish
```